# How to load csv files into a nuxt vue component

Tags: d3.js, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I am currently trying to load a csv file into a Nuxt page. The folder structure is below and produces the error **"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)"**:

```
Project
  |
  +--pages
      |
      +--lesson
          |
         +--index.vue
         +--file.csv

import * as d3 from 'd3';
    export default{
    data(){
    return{
     dataset1:[]
    }

mounted(){

  d3.csv('file.csv', (myData) => {
  console.log('Mydta', myData);
  this.dataset1 = myData;
 })
 }
}
```

I have added the following to the web pack config in the nuxt-folder:

```
  build: {
/*
** You can extend webpack config here
*/
extend(config, ctx) {
  config = {
    module: {
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.csv$/,
          loader: 'csv-loader',
          options: {
            dynamicTyping: true,
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
 }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: I expect it to try to load the resource relative to the route url, not relative to the file path. Have you checked that the file path for your csv is correct?

Comment: How would i amend it to target the route can I use the ~ or @ or would it need to be the full path?

Comment: I recon importing the csv in your component using an import statement, then using `d3.csv.parse(..)` on it is the most sensible option. No need for an api call when the data is within the same folder.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had the same question and ended up using the [@nuxt/content](https://content.nuxtjs.org/) module – worked like a charm, didn't even need to include d3 (which is usually my go-to for parsing CSV files).

Comment: Nice, could you be more specific? Cause on https://content.nuxtjs.org/guide/writing/csv is like 0 instructions how to do this with csv.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue is you cannot access the csv file the way you are attempting to, the way to do that would be storing the file  in the ['/assets'](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/assets) directory which you can then access as shown in the docs I linked `~/assets/file.csv` I think this is also a more correct location for storing such files to avoid having lingering files throughout the project

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
  async mounted() {
    const d = await d3.csv("/data.csv");
    console.log(d);
  }
```

With data.csv placed in **public** folder.